# Extract the text of same html tags in separate lines with JSoup on Android

Tags: android, html, kotlin, jsoup

I have this html code:

```
<li itemprop="something">Text 1</li><li itemprop="something">Text 2</li><li itemprop="something">Text 3</li><li itemprop="something">Text 4</li><li itemprop="something">Text 5 </li><li itemprop="something">Text 6 </li>
```

When I use the following code to extract the text, it gives me them continuous.

```
val doc = Jsoup.parse(html)
val element = doc.select("li[itemprop=something]")
val text = element.text()
```

output:

```
Text 1 Text 2 Text 3 Text 4 Text 5 Text 6
```

but I want them in separate lines:

```
Text 1
Text 2
Text 3
Text 4
Text 5
Text 6
```

Do you guys know how is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `element` object is actually an [`Elements`](https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/select/Elements.html#select-java.lang.String-) object, which has a [`eachText()`](https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/select/Elements.html#eachText--) method returning a `List` containing the text for each of the matched elements.

On the other hand, the [`text()`](https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/select/Elements.html#text--) method returns "the combined text of all the matched elements" (which has no line break as @Roland said, that's why you get all the elements on 1 line).

So, in general you should do something like:

```
doc.select("xxx").eachText().forEach(::println)
```

Comment: Should be `.forEach(::println)`. Just saw too late that actually the `forEach` or `map` or `eachText` was missing :-)

Comment: well... writing it on the fly *and* putting the links on it... good enough ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Your `li`-element does not contain a new line and that is why the text just gets appended at the end if you print it.

And you are actually using `text()` on the `Elements` which are returned by your `select`. You either need to map each single entry to text first (`eachText()` or `map { it.text() }`) and append all those returned to your database or print them directly using `println` or add your preferred new line character at the end before printing it. By the way you didn't mention how you print the text, however I think that's not that important to solve your problem.

Comment: Sorry I didn't get what you mean by "add your preferred new line character at the end"

Comment: Depending on how you print it, you may need to add a new line character (`\n` or `\r\n`, or...) yourself, as your `li`-text does not contain any.

Comment: I store `val text` in database and then retrieve it from database and show it in a text view.